# Calculating Worth of Coins (Cryptocurrency)

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a data source which have session ID , TransactionID , Cryptocurrency , Balance of coin and Market Rate

I am tying to find out worth of coin remaining in customer wallet using this formula

a = MAX({Fixed [Session ID] : SUM([Quantity])})
//// this should be the value of coins remaining in customer account on his last transaction ID

b  = IF [Transacntion ID]={MAX([Transacntion ID])} THEN [Market Rate] END
/// this should be market  rateof currency by latest transaction ID irrespective of customer

c = a * sum(c)
 /// worth of coins

Anyone know how to calculate it ?

remaining coins should depends on customer ID Filter
but Latest market rate should be selected from Max Transaction Date present in the for that currency